# Override instance attribute

Tags: python, django, class, models, manyrelatedmanager

In `views.py` I have:

```
my_computer = Computer.objects.get(pk=some_value)
```

The computer object has a field called projects that's a `ManyRelatedManager`.

Calling

```
my_projects = my_computer.projects.all()
```

will set the value of `my_projects` to a list of three project objects.

What I'm trying to achive is to set the value of `my_computer.projects` to the above list of projects instead of the `ManyRelatedManager`.

I have tried:

```
my_computer.projects = my_projects
```

but that doesn't work, although it doesn't raise an error either. The value of `my_computer.projects` is still the `ManyRelatedManager`.

Comment: This is not clear. You already get the attribute from `my_computer.projects`, why do you want to set it back to that attribute?

Comment: I can get it's value but I can't change it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman to `my_computer.projects.all()`

Comment: Now I am very confused. You want to set `my_computer.projects` to the value of `my_computer.projects.all()`? You mean you just want to remove the necessity to add the `.all()`? Why?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes, that's what I want. I want to do that because afterwards I want to edit the projects list in order to add some extra attributes to the projects before passing them to the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Manager` objects implement `__set__` - they behave as descriptors.

This means you cannot change the object by assigning it (as long as its attribute of another object - `__set__` is only called in the context of `__setattr__` on the parent object - parent regarding composition relationships, and not inheritance relationships).

You can assign any list-like (actually: iterable) value to a manager if such iterable value yields models of the expected type. **However** this means:

1. When you query `my_computer.projects`, you will get again a manager object, with the objects you assigned.
2. When you save the object `my_computer`, only the specified objects will belong to the relationship - previous object in the relationship will not be related anymore to the current object.

There are three scenarios you could have which led you to this issue:

1. You need to hold a volatile list - this data is not stored, in any way, but used temporarily. You have to create a normal attribute in the class:

   ```
   class Computer(models.Model):
       #normal database fields here

       def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
           super(Computer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
           #ENSURE this attribute name does not collide with any field
           #I'm assuming the Many manager name is projects.
           self.my_projects = []
   ```
2. You need another representation of the exact same relationship - in this way, you want a comfortable way to access the object, instead of calling a strange .all(), e.g. to do a `[k.foo for k in mycomputer.my_projects]`. You have to create a property like this:

   ```
   class Computer(models.Model):
       #Normal database fields here
       #I'm assuming the Many manager name is projects.

       @property
       def my_projects(self):
           #remember: my_projects is another name.
           #it CANNOT collide, so I have another
           #name - cannot use projects as name.
           return list(self.projects.all())

       @my_projects.setter
       def my_projects(self, value):
           #this only abstracts the name, to match
           #the getter.
           self.projects = value
   ```
3. You need another relationship (so it's not volatile data): Create ANOTHER relationship in your model, pointing to the same mode, using the same `through` if applicable, **but using a different related_name= (you must explicitly set related_name for at least one of the multiple relationships to the same model, from the same model)**

Comment: Nice answer, but it would be nice if you world add a workaround to it like Daniel Roseman suggested for future references.

Comment: It was modified, adding 3 possible cases I thought about. For the comment I saw, you need the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. Your best bet is to simply use another attribute name.

```
my_computer.related_projects = list(my_computer.projects.all())
```